# C++ How do I configure Eclipse:Oxygen to do line by line debugging on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, gdb

I need directions on how to configure Eclipse to do line by line debugging for C++. I have looked at tutorials and videos everywhere on this and none of them actually work. I know I need to install gdb and have done so using brew. The path to my gdb install is '/usr/local/Cellar/gdb/8.0.1/bin/gdb'. If I set this path as my debugger in Eclipse and hit debug after setting a break point, it runs and never hits the break point.

If there is a better IDE for debugging C++ on OSX that actually works, Ill accept directions for configuring that IDE as an acceptable answer.

Comment: Is the source code built with the debugging symbols? Kindly provide some minimal example in which you are facing this issue.

Comment: I downloaded eclipse on OSX and asked it to make a simple helloworld C++ application. I clicked on the border and put a break point. Next I clicked on the project folder and hit build. Next I clicked on the executable and then clicked the debug button. It runs the code and provides output but does not stop on breakpoints. I can repeat these steps in Ubuntu on a VM and i stops on the breakpoint. This leads me to believe it is something with OSX.

Comment: Are you on `Debug` view in Eclipse?